# Can we use HttpRequestMessage instead of HttpRequest class in Entry function Run in Azure functions v2?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am creating v2 azure functions in .net core 2.0 to be hosted in Linux platform. 
When I create new azure function in visual studio the req parameter for Run function is HttpRequest.
Can I can this to HttpRequestMessage? I want to read Authorization header easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Functions 2.x's HttpTrigger recognizes [HttpRequestMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=netcore-2.2), so there shouldn't be any problems substituting it for HttpRequest. (Either class exposes the Authorization header, though.)

Answer (score 0):

In the version I installed - *Visual Studio 15.9.6* - with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` *1.0.14* the default template even suggested `HttpRequestMessage`.

With this simple version I can access and log Authorization header:

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        log.Info(req.Headers.Authorization.ToString());
```